# Authenticate multiple Rails servers against Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

We have a monolithic Rails 3 (Ruby 1.9) server that does **everything** for us, including Devise session authentication.

We have recently decided to introduce a new Rails 5 server (built from scratch) which will serve as an API server and slowly replace existing capabilities in the old server.

Our problem is that session authentication happens against the old rails server and we want to include session authentication in the new Rails 5 server.

Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to use new rails servers authenticate sessions against an existing rails server which has session information?

Needless to say, my main focus is on Front End development - server side authentication is not my forte.

Comment: I assume they work off the same DB, does your rails 5 app have the same devise logic setup? Your two options are to either replicate the login logic in your rails 5 app, or submit a request from there to your rails 3 one, which I guess would defeat the purpose.

Comment: We're concerned that changing authentication introduces too much of a risk for this sprint. Can we use a method in the application_controller of Rails5 which queries Rails3 and receives in response the current_user and relevant session data?

Comment: You can, it's pretty trivial to setup a new end point that returns the current user's ID (and maybe an associated token if you're worried about security). That still leaves the actual authentication happening with your old server though, they would need to be logged in to return that data

Comment: And do you really want to use session based authentication on an API server?

Comment: @max what are my other options? I want to be able to have generic methods in the API server that render results of rows which are strictly associated with the current user logged in

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple Rails applications that share the same database and that use Device to authenticate users. But you need to ensure the same input / algorithm is used when encrypting passwords.

For Devise this has been BCrypt by default for quite some time, you also need to ensure that the `config.stretches` setting matches for both apps. The implementation has changed a bit over the years through and your milage may vary.

The key concept here is that you´re not authenticating against an application - you're authenticating that the result of encrypting the password provided by the user matches the digest in the database.

But you should also start by recognising that the apps might not have the same authentication requirements at all. Most API's (at least good ones) use token based authentication which is stateless.

One major issue with session based authentication is that cookies normally work on a single domain or subdomains and they are normally disabled by browser if they work cross-domain (3rd party cookies) which means that your will have issues if your api and the legacy app are not on the same subdomain. Cookies are also a feature only available in browsers while token based authentication works in any kind of client.

And while you could have your new application query the legacy application over HTTP tinkering with this might actually be a a waste of time since the new application will need its own authentication solution anyways.

There are multiple gems that provide token based authentication for Devise.

Comment: I'll explore this option and post back with my findings, thanks!